# You have background tasks running. Are you sure you want to cancel them and exit IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When closing IntelliJ 10, if I have tasks running in the background, I'm prompted with this question:

[image]

So if I click "exit" does it mean that the IntelliJ will exit without cancelling the background tasks and if I click "cancel" IntelliJ will cancel the tasks and then exit?

Answer (score 1):

Exiting cancels the background tasks and exits intellij.

Cancelling the exit, well it cancels the exit and everything carries on.

(Not exactly the best question, voted to close btw)

Comment: I think it's not a bad question, since he's talking about cancelling tasks, the "cancel" button could lead users to believe that those tasks will be canceled.

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine He? You asked the question.  Its standard language used everywhere. It makes sense to everyone else. But from your comment, you still don't "get it" ... the tasks are cancelled!

Comment: I don't think that from my comment you can draw the conclusion that I didn't understand your answer.